# sqlite 1 to many schema: query rows linked to itemX and itemY only

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with a one to many relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE 'tag' (
    'id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    'value' TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE ('value')
);

CREATE TABLE 'tagfile' (
    'idFile' INTEGER NOT NULL,
    'idTag' INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('idFile', 'idTag'),
    FOREIGN KEY(idFile) REFERENCES tracks(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(idTag) REFERENCES tag(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

How can I query it to get list of idFile:

- linked to AND ONLY TO a given list of tag.value ? (PREVENT idFile to have links to other data from tag table)
- linked to AT LEAST a given list of tag.value ? (ALLOW idFile to have links to other data from tag table)

Comment: Do not surround column names with single quotes.  That is a really bad habit, even if SQLite accepts it in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select tf.idFile
from tagfile tf join
     tag t
     on tf.idtag = t.id
where t.value in ('a', 'b', 'c')
group by tf.idFile
having count(*) = 3;  -- length of list
```

If you want files that have those three and others, then use the above.  If you want exactly those three:

```
select tf.idFile
from tagfile tf join
     tag t
     on tf.idtag = t.id
group by tf.idFile
having sum(case when t.value in ('a', 'b', 'c') then 1 else 0 end) = 3 and
       count(*) = 3;  -- length of list
```

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. Any idea for the other one (to AT LEAST) ?

Comment: Humm, having count(*) >= 3; should do !

Comment: having count(*) >= 3 does not the trick since the 3 items can be different than those requested :(

Comment: Thanks. Will try this tomorrow. Too late now

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using this solution though it requires tags not to overlap (or some weird results may happen but not a big deal in my case).
If anyone has a better query though, I'd be glad to hear from :)

```
select tf.idFile, GROUP_CONCAT(t.value) AS tags
from tagfile tf join
     tag t
     on tf.idtag = t.id
group by tf.idFile
having tags LIKE "%a%"
AND tags LIKE "%b%"
AND tags LIKE "%c%"
AND tags NOT LIKE "%d%" -- to filter out
```

**Edit:**
Finally using solution from Gordon. Here is another version:

```
select tf.idFile, GROUP_CONCAT(t.value) AS tags
from tagfile tf join
     tag t
     on tf.idtag = t.id
group by tf.idFile
-- Those to include: ( = length of include list)
having sum(case when t.value in ('a', 'b', 'c') then 1 else 0 end) = 3  
-- Those to exclude: ( = 0)
and sum(case when t.value in ('z', 'y') then 1 else 0 end) = 0          
 -- for exact list match, add:
 -- and count(*) = 3 -- ( = length of include list)
```